# Load string local address in Glide library

Tags: android, android-glide

I have a database and I could set image address in **String** like this `"R.mipmap.image"`.
But how can I use this String in Glide library to open a picture? (Only **String** address for local image)

```
Glide.with(this).load(???).into(image);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use identifier to get desire image

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
return res.getDrawable(res.getIdentifier(idName, "drawable", context.getPackageName()));
```